# How to preserve DataGridView color information (both cell and text) when using column filters?

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors

I use AdvancedDataGridView in my project. I can change my desired cells (and text) color using right click menu, but when I use column filters, all those color information got lost. Even when I remove filters, those color information don't get back to its place.
I have designed a class for saving/loading DGV color information when opening/exiting the application:

```
      public static void WriteDataGridViewSettings(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dgv)
    {
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(Application.StartupPath + @"\MyGridColor.xml", null);
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement(dgv.Name);
        int LastRow = dgv.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < LastRow; i++)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("Row");
            writer.WriteStartElement("CellColor");
            writer.WriteString(dgv.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor.ToArgb().ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteStartElement("TextColor");
            writer.WriteString(dgv.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor.ToArgb().ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
        writer.Close();
    }

    public static void ReadDataGridViewSettings(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dgv)
    {
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNodeList xmlnode;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + @"\MyGridColor.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        xmldoc.Load(fs);
        xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Row");
            for (int i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count-1; i++)
            {
                int cellcolor = int.Parse(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim());
                int textcolor = int.Parse(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText.Trim());
                if (cellcolor != 0)
                {
                    dgv.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(cellcolor));
                    dgv.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(textcolor));
                }
                else
                {
                    dgv.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                    dgv.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                }
            }
        fs.Close();
    }
```

Because of the problem mentioned above, I have accidentally lost my color information after using the filter and exiting the application.

Comment: What is the `AdvancedDataGridView` you're using?

Comment: I have downloaded it from Package Manager. DG.AdvancedDataGridView

Comment: Probably what is happening is the filter is redrawing all the rows when the `BindingSource` is filtered. I recommend you do your row colouring in the `AdvancedDataGridView.RowPrePaint` event, based on your criteria for colouring a row. How are you determining which rows need colouring? I seems like you're just colouring based on the position they were written into the file, which will obviously break when you start changing the positions of the rows via filtering.

Comment: There are no specific criteria for coloring a row. I have just designed a right-click menu and use it for changing the color of my desired row. I think there is no problem with my load/save color code. I just need to do something to avoid redrawing all the rows.  Can you give your solution in code so I can have a better understanding?

Comment: I would recommend you add a hidden column to your `DataGridView` which has a unique index for each row assigned when you populate the data. Then you can store the list of indexes which should be coloured and do the colouring in `RowPrePaint` based on if the index is in the list.

Comment: OK, Do you mean I have to add hidden index numbers to DGV and use MY right-click menu code in RowPrePaint event handler?

Comment: like this: private void dataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so here is a working solution. You will need to adapt it to meet your exact requirements, but it should give you an idea of how you can persist colours across at datagridview when the rows get redrawn.

The idea is we store some unique identifier for each row in a list and then we use that identifier to decide if (or what) colour the row should be, and apply that in the `RowPrePaint` event.

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingSource _bs = new BindingSource();
    
    //If you want to store associated colours for each row
    //expand this to whatever data structure you prefer
    List<int> _colourRows = new List<int>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This is the normal data from, for example, a database
        DataTable table = ExampleData();

        //Now add an extra column and put some unique numbers in the datatable
        //We do it to the underlying data
        //If your data already has a unique index or sequence you don't need to do this
        table.Columns.Add("sequenceColumn", typeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i <= table.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            table.Rows[i]["sequenceColumn"] = i;
        }

        //Bind data to the UI
        _bs.DataSource = table;
        dgv.DataSource = _bs;

        //Hide this column from UI
        dgv.Columns["sequenceColumn"].Visible = false;
        dgv.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    }

    private void setColourToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgv.SelectedRows)
        {
            //Add it to the list and also update it immediately
            _colourRows.Add((int)dr.Cells["sequenceColumn"].Value);
            dr.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }

    private void dgv_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //The key is that this isn't the rows position index (which could change with filtering sorting)
        //It is just a value we've added to a new column for each row
        int rowColourSequence = (int)dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["sequenceColumn"].Value;

        if (_colourRows.Contains(rowColourSequence))
        {
            dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }

    private DataTable ExampleData()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Animal", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));

        table.Rows.Add("Cat", 15);
        table.Rows.Add("Dog", 10);
        table.Rows.Add("Ferret", 2);
        table.Rows.Add("Mouse", 0);

        return table;
    }
}
```

Here you can see if I change the sorting or filtering the row colour is persisted:

[image: first image]
[image: second image]
[image: third image]